# Should keyword arguments with default values always be considered optional by the caller in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, system-design

I'm trying to decide if raising an exception when the caller doesn't override a default keyword argument value is poor design. Put another way, should keyword arguments with default values always be considered optional by the caller?

My goal, I believe, is to extend functionality without breaking older code.

Image a design where:

- Base class specifies a method signature: `foo()`.
- Child class needs to extend the functionality of `foo()` but this requires additional information.
- So the child class overrides `foo()` and adds a keyword argument for capturing the additional information: `foo(bar=None)`.

The problem is the child class' `foo` implementation cannot use the value `bar=None`. It needs the caller to provide a valid `bar` value because there's no known default that can work. (`None` is used in the method signature to avoid explicitly breaking inheritance.)

From a design perspective, is it poor form to raise an exception (e.g., `TypeError`) if the caller does not explicitly provide a `bar` value, such as `child.foo(bar='some_value')`?

### Detailed Context

I'm designing a library that allows a remote system to be controlled via Python. The remote system is ultimately controlled via its command-line tools. The library attempts to abstract away details about the remote system (e.g., version, environment, operating system) so users can focus on simply controlling the system. It's essentially mapping Python operations to shell commands for controlling the remote system, then running those commands. The library will be used for automated black-box testing of remote systems.

Importantly, the library needs to work against multiple versions of the remote software (e.g., v1, v2, v3), and the command syntax can vary between versions (e.g., the command might require more arguments in one version than the other). I want to account for this while duplicating as little code as possible.

My proposed solution is to begin with a class containing all the commands available in v1. I'll then create a subclass for commands in v2, overriding only methods for commands whose syntax has changed since v1. The will allow users to simply add new arguments when needed (depending on the software version being tested) without breaking inheritance by fully changing the method signature.

For example (in the contrived example below), `BaseCommands` contains the commands available in v1. `CommandsVersion2` overrides commands whose syntax has changed. `CommandVersion2` overrides the `start_system` because in v2, more information is required (`username`) and raises an exception if the caller does not replace the default value.

*Is raising the exception when the caller doesn't replace the default value poor design?*

```python
class BaseCommands:
  """ Builds shell commands to be run on the remote system. """
  
  @staticmethod
  def display_message(*, message:str)->str:
    """ Command for displaying a message on the remote system. """
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    return f'config.sh -display \"[{timestamp}] {message}\"'


  @staticmethod
  def start_system()->str:
    """ Command for starting the remote system. """
    return 'config.sh -start'


class CommandsVersion2(BaseCommands):
  """ Defines commands available in software v2."""

  @staticmethod
  def start_system(*,username:str=None)->str:
    """ Software v2 requires specifying who is starting the system. """
    if username is None:
        raise TypeError('username is required in Software v2.')
    return f'config.sh -start -user \"{username}\"'
```

The library might be used in tests like this:

*v1_tests.py*

```python
@test
def test_startup():
  cmd = BaseCommands.start_system()
  result = LinuxTerminal().run(cmd)
  assertTrue(result.success)
```

*v2_tests.py*

```python
@test test_startup():
  cmd = CommandsVersion2.start_system(user
  result = LinuxTerminal().run(cmd)
  assertTrue(result.success)
```

Comment: What's the point of having a default value if it's not optional?

Comment: "The will allow users to simply add new arguments when needed (depending on the software version being tested) without breaking inheritance by fully changing the method signature." - but you *are* effectively changing the signature. An override that pretends an extra argument is optional, but raises an error if it receives the default value, is no more compatible with the superclass signature than an override that just makes the extra argument mandatory through the ordinary mechanisms for making arguments mandatory.

Comment: @Barmar The idea was to not break inheritance by changing the method signature. But thinking more about it (and as user2357112 has now pointed out) the point of not changing the method signature is allowing the caller to pass arguments without knowing exactly the object's exact subclass. Raising an exception when the default value isn't changed breaks that contract. Even worse, it requires the library user to know they need to provide the argument without giving them any hints.

Comment: @Michael *Parameters* have default values; keyword *arguments* are a way to provide values for parameters at call time. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: @chepner: I think correction that falls into the category "technically correct, the best kind of correct". People use "arguments" to mean both, and it's a bit of a lost cause to correct them outside of the most formal contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of having a default value is to make an argument optional.

So the answer is: yes, it's poor design to raise an exception when a keyword argument has a default value and isn't overridden.

In contrast, if there is no default value defined, then it's good design to detect that immediately and raise an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You decide how your code should be called. Always using keyword arguments is reasonable. And having a function with a required argument is normal as well.

Allow me to add, though: your reason to do so requires prior knowledge of how one version changes to the next. Imagine v1 is totally different from v2: then sub classing makes little sense. Or v1 differs from v2 where other methods of handling both might be more optimal.

Another thing: `None` might be an inadequate sentinel to detect the missing argument. The caller might have actually used `None`.

Comment: But if the argument is required, the default value is pointless (and no, you don't need a default value for a keyword argument - default values and keyword arguments are completely unrelated things that just happen to have similar syntax).